# Uniquely identify that a request is coming from a particular installation of my extension

Tags: security, authentication, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

I am developing a chrome extension that needs to communicate with my server. I am using Google Server side oauth for authentication. When the user first installs the extension, he needs to login using google and after the oauth server side flow, my server sends user a unqiueid which my extension stores in the localstorage. Every subsequent request to my server is a post request with uuid being part of the payload to authenticate the user. Now the issue with this scenario is that I am not sure how secure this technique is, as i believe anybody could take someone's else uuid and store it in his localstorage thus being able to access other people's account. I  know i could use ssl for request between my server and client to prevent eavesdropping of  request/response from my server, but even than if i have personal access to somebody else's computer i could easily copy the uuid. I want to know is there any better way of authentication for the extensions without asking user to sign in using oauth everytime he intends to use my extension.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you only want to store this UUID for a specified period of time. After all, the access tokens you get for the user may be revoked at a later date.

But for the duration of the delegated login you could make your UUID more secure by 'noncing' it with some additional 'unique' information about the client, such as their IP address and session cookie. So basically concatenating a set of uniquely identifying pieces of information together, then signing them with your public key before storing on the client side. Something similar too:

```
token = encrypt: UUID + client IP + sessionID
```

And on the server side you would do:

```
raw = decrypt: token
UUID = uuidPart: raw
assignedIP = ipPart: raw
assignedSessionID = idPart: raw
verifyMatch: assignedIP, currentIP
verifyMatch: assignedSessionID, currentSessionID
```

To successfully masquerade as another user, the attacked would need to have both the token, and also the same IP as the original client, which is a couple steps more secure than your previous setup.

Comment: I am novice in cryptography and didn't understood how this will prevent simple cut and paste attacks. Pardon me if i am wrong, but wont the nonce make the uuid useless, next time my client tries to login using the uuid as the session cookie and/or ipaddress might be different. It would be great if you could elaborate your answer.

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. How long are you planning on keeping these uuid's around?

Comment: I intend to keep the uuid for as many days as access token is valid or  until user logs out. I use couple of bookmarking extensions which works similarly. they use oauth for authentication, but i don't need to login to them everytime. I only need to login only when i clear my cache or some x number of days after. Example -> diigo bookmarking extension, save to pulse etc.

Comment: My only issue with  the above posted example is that, as soon as user ip address changes, his locally stored uuid is no longer useful and he needs to login again. For the above mentioned extensions, this is not a limitation. Besides for these extensions, i don't see anything stored in the local storage or cookies as well. I would love to do something similar and really appreciate if you could help